# How many iPhone apps can I distribute with a single enrollment?

Tags: iphone, distribution

I'm signed in the standard program of iPhone Developer Program.
How many apps can I distribute with my account?

EDIT: I want to distribute my apps only using AppStore

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Standard and Enterprise Programs allow you to share your application with up to 100 other iPhone or iPod touch users with Ad Hoc distribution. Share your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/distribute.html

You can distribute as many as you want over the iphone store

However keep in mind that apps have to be approved before they are added to the app store.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is as many as you want

Comment: But please don't become the next Khalid Shaikh: http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2009/08/03/apple-bans-app-stores-3rd-most-prolific-developer/